# Python Variables and Strings

Tags: python, types

I need to know if a variable in Python is a string(name) or a number. I want to check out the degree of graphs, however I need to know if "i" iterator, is a number inside of the string or a name inside of the string, showing the degree of graphs at the end.

Is there something wrong in this code?

```
import csv, sys
import networkx as nx

def ministro_lei():

    stf = csv.reader(open('resultset.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    eds = [(i[0],i[1],i[2]) for i in stf]
    G = nx.DiGraph(nome='ministro_lei')
    G.add_weighted_edges_from(eds)
    for i in G.degree():
        if isinstance(i,str):
            print (" This is a name:", i)
        elif isinstance(i, int):
            print ("This is a number: ", i)
        else:
            raise ValueError 
    return G, eds
```

ministro_lei = ()

Here lies some examples of outs:

```
  "MIN. OCTAVIO GALLOTTI",53,109
  "MIN. SYDNEY SANCHES",13,109
  "MIN. JOAQUIM BARBOSA",101,108
```

Please any help?
Thanks

Comment: Could you be more precise in what you are asking? It's totally unclear at least for me what do you want.

Comment: Your "normal" `return` at the end of the method `ministro_lei` returns two variables. However, there are two more `return (i)` lines within the loops, that return single variables. This structure will never pass past the first iteration of the for-loop. Is this what you want?

Comment: I is a list.  Not an int or a string

Comment: That is right, a list indeed..thank you joel..

Comment: If one of the answers works for you, you should accept it (click on the greet checkmark by it).

Answer (score 2):

They must be strings since `",".join(i)` would have returned a TypeError if `i` were an `int`.

But, in general, to find out the type of a variable, use `type`:

```
print(type(i))
```

Comment: it looks to me like i is a list.  Not a string or an integer.

Comment: @joelgoldstick: Hm. The code has changed after I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(s) is str
True
>>> n = 6
>>> type(n)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(n) is int
True
```